# How to generate an array in each process and in these processes find the minimum value of its generated part

Tags: c++, mpi

I need generate an array in each process and in these processes find the minimum value of its generated part.I do not understand how to divide the generation into parts and find the minimum value in these parts.

```
int rank, num_procs;
double result;
int length = 10e6;
double *arr = new double[length];
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

int load = length / num_procs;
auto min = DBL_MAX, max = DBL_MIN;
for (int i = rank * load; i < (rank + 1) * load; ++i) {
    arr[i] = (pow(2 * i, 1 / 3) + 6) / abs(i * cos(i));
    if (arr[i] > max) {
        max = arr[i];
    } 
    if (arr[i] < min) {
        min = arr[i];
    }
}
result = min * max;
cout << result << endl;
MPI_Send(&result, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if (rank == 0) {
    MPI_Recv(&result, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
             MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    result *= result;
    cout << result << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please read the description of the tags you applied and remove the one that doesn't fit.

Comment: A couple of things. ther e is no MPI_Send corresponding to the Recv. Second, May be you can reformulate your question a bit so it is more clear what you want to achieve here.  Here, each rank has an array of length 10e6, that is alot of memory. It is better to allocate only required memory on each rank, 10e6/numprocs.

Comment: how to generate an array on each process that the first process took some quantity, the second process took from the last filled value of the first and filled some quantity and so on and then to find in these parts some value

Comment: "first process took some quantity" Too vague. Take how? From where/what? What do you mean by quantity? And what does the process do with that quantity?

Comment: I need to fill an array with 1 million elements, how to distribute it to all filling processes and in these processes find some value of part of the array

Answer (score 1):

One naive way to do is divide your load (perform the number generation) equally. Say (`load=length/num_procs`). So each process will generate `load` numbers. Basically `rank 0` will generates values from `i=0` to `i=load`, while `rank 1` will generate values from `i=load` to `i=2*load` and so on. Basically, each rank will loop from `i=rank*load` to `i=(rank+1)*load`. *Assumption: `length/num_procs` is divisible.* Otherwise you have to distribute the remaining load.

```
        load=length / num_procs;
        for (int i = rank*load; i < (rank+1)*load; ++i) {
            arr[i] = (pow(2 * i, 1/3) + 6) / abs(i * cos(i));
        }
```

Comment: 0 process also include?, I just need to find the minimum value for each process, pass it 0 and make the sum of these values

Comment: In principle, yes. Otherwise process 0 will stay idle when all other processes perform computation. But if you don't want to do it then, divide the `length` by `num_procs -1` and `rank 1` should start from chunk `i=0` to `i=load`.

Comment: and another question like this value to pass to the zero process through MPI_Send and MPI_Recv?

Comment: Yes, you could use MPI send and recv for that. Alternatively, in such scenarios, MPI collective operations will be useful. For example, you could use `MPI_Gather`

Comment: how to make the correct implementation MPI_Send and MPI_Recv

Comment: This link has some really good examples and explanations. https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-send-and-receive/